# How do I connect to a remote site through the cmd prompt?

Tags: cmd, remote-access, remote-server

I've checked the 'help' command but haven't found anything that seems sufficient to complete this task.

Net view doesn't lead me to the correct location, nor do commands such as ipconfig and start.

I'm certain there is an answer I've yet to find it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. Maybe http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html or http://ss64.com/nt/mstsc.html?

Comment: Googled `remote access windows command line` and immediately saw an answer in [the official docs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-line-parameters-remote-desktop-connection#1TC=windows-7)...